# SQL Server : trigger after insert - question if it is possible to behave diffrently in accordence to different data inserted in xml -

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which contains a `XML` column into which different xml data is being inserted, for example cars and people. I am thinking about writing a trigger that would after insert, insert data from inserted to different table cars into table car, people into table people.

1st XML

```
<Cars>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <brand>Fiat></brand>
    <carColor>Blue</carColor>
</Cars>
```

2nd XML

```
<People>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Name>Luke</Name>
    <LastName>Skywalker</LastName>
</People>
```

DDL

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableThatIsbeingTriggered]
(
    [id] [INT] NULL,
    [xmlData] [XML] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[car]
(
    [ID] [INT] NULL,
    [brand] [NCHAR](10) NULL,
    [carColor] [NCHAR](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[people]
(
    [ID] [INT] NULL,
    [Name] [NCHAR](10) NULL,
    [LastName] [NCHAR](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Is it possible to achieve? Furthermore, If those XML documents contains nodes called statuses for example 'delete', could the trigger behave that way that he delete data that is already existing in that target table depending on the node inside the XML?

Comment: Considering that the only way you could derive the table would be by reading the XML and inspecting the elements, and then (likely) using dynamic SQL, it seems like a bad idea. Why isn't the data just being inserted into the correct table in the first place?

Comment: The application is working that way, it has its own logic and it can not be changed.

Comment: Hey, I guess you're giving a toy example here?  This doesn't look like real application code. If it is, then I agree with @Larnu.  The application needs work (FWIW every application can be changed, whether in-house or 3rd-party.  If it couldn't what what happen with security issues?)

Comment: Can this be done? Sure. It's not convenient or anything, but it can be done. SQL Server has extensive support for processing XML; you can shred the XML values and separate these into inserts, updates and deletes, then perform these statements with the tables as sources. Avoid dynamic SQL if you can; if your tables are known in advance, you can `CASE` on the values. If you don't know them in advance, doing this in T-SQL is going to be very painful; you're better off with a new application that processes the updates separately. You can use query notifications or Service Broker to activate it.

Comment: @ user1443098  Yes this is a toy example. I was just looking for comments if going to do it with T-SQL going to be a pain and at then if it the data processing would be efficient and I would not lose time for nothing.

Comment: While all of this *might* be possible in a trigger - I'd like to put in a **strong warning**: triggers should be very **small and fast** - do **NOT** put any heavy processing or complicated calculations into a trigger. Why? The trigger is being executed **in the transaction** that caused it to be fired, and prevents that transaction from completing. Therefore - **absolutely minimize** the time the trigger takes! If you need to do heavy lifting - think of alternatives, e.g. scheduled SQL tasks etc.